# Trouble in Wazuh 4 production cluster (docker) with lostash ouput in elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, logstash, wazuh

I have the production cluster of Wazuh 4 with open-distro for elasticsearch, kibana and ssl security in docker and I am trying to connect logstash (a docker image of logstash) with elasticsearch and I am getting this:

```
Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error
```

I have generated ssl certificates for logstash, tried other ways (changed the output of logstash , through filebeat modules) to connect without success.
What is the solution for this problem for Wazuh 4?

Comment: Could you share any more details about the logstash image? It should be the `OSS` release to correctly work with opendistro.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! The logstash image is "docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.9.3". So, it is OSS. But i think the problem is something with wazuh configuration? Maybe i have to make something with the filebeat and logstash.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you with this. Our current documentation is valid for distributed architectures where Logstash is installed on the same machine as Elasticsearch, so we should consider adding documentation for the proper configuration of separated Logstash instances.

Ok, now let’s see if we can fix your problem.

After installing Logstash, I assume that you configured it using the distributed configuration file, as seen on [this step](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/open-distro/index.html) (Logstash.2.b). Keep in mind that you need to specify the Elasticsearch IP address at the bottom of the file:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["<PUT_HERE_ELASTICSEARCH_IP>:9200"]
        index => "wazuh-alerts-3.x-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "wazuh"
    }
}
```

After saving the file and restarting the Logstash service, you may be getting this kind of log message on */var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log*:

```
Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://192.168.56.104:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://192.168.56.104:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
```

I discovered that we need to edit the Elasticsearch configuration file, and modify this setting: network.host. On my test environment, this setting appears commented like this:

```
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
```

And I changed it to this:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

(Notice that I removed the ***#*** at the beginning of the line). The 0.0.0.0 IP will make Elasticsearch listen on all network interfaces.

After that, I restarted the Elasticsearch service using ***systemctl restart elasticsearch***, and then, I started to see the alerts being indexed on Elasticsearch. Please, try these steps, and let’s see if everything is properly working now.

Let me know if you need more help with this, I’ll be glad to assist you.

Regards,